# Can I reorder the column of wxDataViewCtrl programmatically

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

We can reorder the wxDataViewCtrl columns via drag and drop in the control.
But I want to reorder the column of wxDataViewCtrl in the control programmatically.

I am looking for API like `ReorderColumn(unsigned int pos, wxDataViewColumn *col)`

API for adding, deleting and inserting a columns are available. But I did not find  any direct API to achieve the reordering.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this directly currently, you will need to use `DeleteColumn()` and `InsertColumn()` to swap the columns manually.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. Another issue, if I reorder a column in control. I am not getting wxEVT_DATAVIEW_COLUMN_REORDERED event. I am on Windows

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, currently this event is only generated in the OS X version. It should be simple enough to add support for it to the others but nobody has done it yet...

Answer (score 0):

Add wxDATAVIEW_COL_REORDERABLE flag when you create column

Comment: This doesn't help at all with reordering the columns programmatically, which was the point of the question.